# Is there any reason Python 3 would execute a statement twice?

Tags: python, pdb, statements

I have a function:

```
def turn(self, keyEvent):

    if (keyEvent.key == pygame.locals.K_UP) and \
       (self.body[0].direction != Directions.DOWN):
        self._pivotPoints.append(PivotPoint(self.body[0].location, \
        Directions.UP))
        print("Placing pivot point up")

    #elif chain for the down left and right button presses omitted
    #code is the same for each input
```

that creates instances of the following class:

```
class PivotPoint:
    def __init__(self, location, \
                 direction):
        """When a body part reaches a pivot point, it changes directions"""
        pdb.set_trace()
        self.location = location
        self.direction = direction
```

When I run this code, pdb fires up, and I get the following sequence of I/O:

```
> /home/ryan/Snake/snake.py(50)__init__()
-> self.location = location
(Pdb) step
> /home/ryan/Snake/snake.py(51)__init__()
-> self.direction = direction
(Pdb) step
--Return--
> /home/ryan/Snake/snake.py(51)__init__()->None
-> self.direction = direction
(Pdb) step
> /home/ryan/Snake/snake.py(89)turn()
-> print("Placing pivot point right")
```

The statement on line 51 is being executed twice. Why is this so?

Comment: Is `self.direction` a property?

Comment: It's just the last line of the function and it will return `None` because no `return` is specified. There's no running the line again

Comment: @Mehrdad It's intent is to be a variable. If my syntax is wrong it may be a property to the interpreter, but I doubt it. I have posted the class in its current entirety as of right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The line is not being executed again.**

```
> /home/ryan/Snake/snake.py(51)__init__()->None
```

It means: This is the return point of the function because you did not added a `return` (because `__init__` methods should only return None anyway).

If you check the bytecode, it will show something like that at the end:

```
         28 LOAD_CONST               1 (None) 
         31 RETURN_VALUE
```

meaning the function will actually return `None` even if it is not specified.

So, `pdb` is telling you the function is returning to its caller and it will show the last line of said function to represent that.